# Invented templates having no valid specializations

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The Standard [says](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template [...]

The Standard also has various rules that stipulate inventing or rewriting templates, producing new templates that are not contained in the source program. What happens if such invented or rewritten template has no valid specializations? Can it happen when all user templates do have valid specializations?

Consider this code (lifted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895035/is-a-template-with-reference-non-type-template-parameter-supposed-to-match-a-tem)):

```
template<template<int&> class> struct A {};
template<auto> struct B {};
A<B> a;
```

The code is accepted by all major compilers.

Checking whether `A<B>` is allowed involves synthesizing these templates with unique invented names:

```
template <auto> class X {};
template<auto V> void func1(X<V>);
template<int& V> void func2(X<V>);
```

and then checking the partial template ordering between `func1` and `func2` to see which one is more specialized.

It looks like `func2` has no valid specializations. At least I could not produce one. Yet both `A` and `B` are perfectly normal templates with valid specializations.

Comment: I would imagine that the compiler should never invent "invalid" template based on correct code, for example in the case of templated lambdas. Meaning if the templated `operator()` is invalid it is due to user writing incorrect code. But it is hard to prove a negative since it seems to me like you are asking whether the Standard is internally consistent.

Comment: Since those invented templates are usually created from some user template for the purposes of overload resolution (or some such), I will argue that it can only happen if the source user template is ill-formed;ndr itself.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica See update for an example.

Comment: '*It looks like func2 has no valid specializations"* - What's wrong with `static int v; func2(X<v>);`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica `auto` doesn't deduce to a reference type.

Comment: Ahh, right right. So all arguments will be futile. But while partial ordering is "rigged" in this case, it does give a consistent result. I guess the question is whether this really matters for internally invented templates, since they serve as nothing more than an entry point to an algorithm.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes that's the question; another question is why this rule (of no valid specializations) exists at all. It is generally impossible to check.

Comment: Same reason the ODR exists, despite it being intractable to check in the general case. There's a plethora of programs that can exhibit weird behavior, if such things are permissible. This rule closes the gap (it's not allowed by omission), even though there is no checking it. Just contract law.

Comment: In general, the "no valid specialization" rules are about the quality of implementation. If a compiler is able to find a error in a template before it's instantiated, why not allow it to do so.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why consider it an error? Normal code that would exhibit an error but is never executed is not an error, it's just dead code. Why meta-code that is never executed should be an error?

Comment: If we're talking about compile-time errors, they are diagnosed in dead non-template code.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Checking the ODR is tractable, it's just not feasible with our current (rather primitive) linker technology.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No we're talking about run-time errors ot ordinary code. Run-time of meta-code is compile-time of ordinary code, so to speak.

Comment: It's really not. The ODR deals in types too.

Comment: *"Run-time of meta-code is compile-time of ordinary code, so to speak"* That's an interesting idea. Ok, a different example. Consider two-phase lookup, for example. If you perform the phase-one lookup when parsing the declaration (as you should; not when substituting template arguments, to avoid doing it several times), then why not diagnose the error immediately when you see it, rather than delaying it to a specialization?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This is an interesting question. I don't know. Perhaps we can consider templates not as indivisible units but as a collection of code snippets. Snippets that do not depend on template parameters are diagnosed immediately. But I have no strong opinion one way or the other.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes, and why don't linkers support types (of arbitrary entities, not just functions by the way of mangling) and type checking? But hey this is for another question...

Comment: *"I have no strong opinion one way or the other"* And neither do the committee members, apparently, hence NDR. :) Compilers have different behavior as well: MSVC is incredibly lazy in its diagnostics, I think it ignores errors in non-instantiated templates completely (and since it doesn't need `typename`, apparently it performs the substitution on the token level - scandalous), while Clang (and GCC, to some extent) try to diagnose as early as possible.

Comment: Well, I don't think "no valid specialization can be generated" is true in this case. See https://godbolt.org/z/Gzzsbdfqv

Comment: Hmm indeed. Quite unexpected.

Comment: Close to https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2067?

Comment: Regarding the interesting discussion on "why" have the rule, I want to add it also allows implementations to parse templates without polluting the syntax tree. For example, do you need to represent arrays with negative lengths? If you allow anything grammatically valid in templates, but don't allow early rejection, maybe you do. Allowing early rejection gives implementations flexibility. But requiring early rejection is difficult.

Comment: @JeffGarrett i don't think this offers much added value. If the implementation sees that a template cannot be instantiated, it can report an error and stop, but it can also mark it as such, kill its internal structure, and move on. There is no need to keep negative length arrays or anything of fhe sort. Just keep one "this is invalid" flag. Give out an error only if an instantiation attempt is detected.

Comment: @n.m. I'm glad I commented because that gives me some real food for thought.