# Template partial ordering and auto and reference NTTP: discrepancy between major compilers

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Lifted from comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895035/is-a-template-with-reference-non-type-template-parameter-supposed-to-match-a-tem).

Consider these templates and a function call:

```
template <int&> struct X{};
template <int& V> int func(X<V>) { return 0; }   
template <auto V> int func(X<V>) { return 1; }

int i;
int main() { return func(X<i>{}); }
```

The three major compilers differ in interpreting this code.

MSVC consider it ambiguous. GCC and Clang choose the first overload. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v46Gj3jEa)

However Clang considers the second overload non-viable, while GCC and MSVC do not. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EW4nev1b6)

If we replace `int&` with `int`, both MSVC and Clang consider the call ambiguous, while gcc still chooses the first overload. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b8dfoosvz)

Which compiler is right? Relevant quotes from the standard will be much appreciated.

Comment: I might be wrong, but non-type parameter cannot be generic, or it's a change in C++20?

Comment: Related [MSVC bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-chooses-specialization-over-primary/10175880)

Comment: Looks like a msvc bug because `auto` cannot be inferred to a reference type so that first overload should be used. Also `i` is not constexpr so `auto` overload cannot be used.

Comment: @JasonLiam doesn't look related to me.

Comment: @n.m. Since these bugs are quite different, here is the newly submitted [msvc bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-program-involving-a/10240207) that addresses this. And here is the [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108234) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [msvc bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-accepts-invalid-program-involving-a/10240207) because the template non-type parameter with `auto` can never be deduced to a *reference type*. This in turn means that the overload with `auto` can only deduce the parameter to be `int` but then that will fail because template arguments must be `constexpr` which `i` is not.

This essentially means that the first overload with `template <int& V>` is the only option left because the second overload is **not viable**. So the program is *well-formed* and the first overload should be used.

This can also be seen from [nontype template parameter documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

> The type of a non-type template parameter may be deduced if it includes a placeholder type (`auto`, a placeholder for a deduced class type (since C++20), or decltype(auto)). **The deduction is performed as if by deducing the type of the variable x in the invented declaration `T x = template-argument;`, where `T` is the declared type of the template parameter.**

(emphasis mine)

This is basically telling us the `x` cannot be a reference type. And so the second overload(with `auto`) in your example is not viable(as `i` is not `constexpr` and `T` is deduced to be `int`) and there is only one version remaining(which is the first overload  with `int&`) and it should be used for the call `func(X<i>{})` in your original example.

---

You can also confirm this by removing the first overload so that the call `func(X<i>{}` will be rejected. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h5q7589Tr). Note that only clang rejects(correctly saying `non-type template argument is not a constant expression`) the call in the modified example while gcc and msvc incorrectly accepts it.

```
 template <int&> struct X{};
       
 template <auto V> int func(X<V>) { return 1; }

 int i;
 int main() 
 { return func(X<i>{}); //only clang correctly rejects this while gcc and msvc accepts this
 }
```

Here is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=108234) for the modified example.

Comment: "non-type parameter with auto can never be deduced to a reference type" Can you quote relevant passage(s) from the standard? The closest I could find is [temp.arg.nontype/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#arg.nontype-1) but it doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: @n.m. I've added statement(s) from cppreference. Hope it helps. Basically the deduction should be as if we are doing `T V = i;` which means `T` will be `int`. But since `i` is not `constexpr`, it cannot be used as a template argument for second overload.  Check out the updated answer.